# How to convert a time format to seconds in solaris

Tags: perl, shell, scripting, opensolaris

I have a time of format `2013-04-29 08:17:58` and I need to convert it into seconds.

In UNIX, we can use `date +%s`. Is there anyway to do it in Solaris?

Comment: You know that Solaris **is** Unix, right?

Comment: i meant in solaris-Ux

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece). It has been part of the standard Perl 5 distribution since version 9.5 and shouldn't need installing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $t = '2013-04-29 08:17:58';

$t = Time::Piece->strptime($t, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');

say $t->epoch;
```

**output**

```
1367223478
```

Comment: perhaps from cmd line, `perl -MTime::Piece -E 'say Time::Piece->strptime(pop,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")->epoch' "2013-04-29 08:17:58"`

Comment: Perl v5.10.0 required--this is only v5.8.4, stopped at abc.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at abc.pl line 3. This is the error i am getting

Comment: @AsishPati: Version 8.4 is *over nine years old*! You really should upgrade. For now you can install `Time::Piece` from CPAN and remove line 3 `use 5.010`.

Comment: @AsishPati: Well you should make some noise about it!

Comment: they will fire me after that... :P

Comment: Versions 14 and earlier are *no longer supported*.

Comment: isnt there any other way. without using perl

Comment: If someone wanted me to use Perl 5.8.4, they wouldn't need to fire me - I'd resign on the spot :-)

Comment: Well, isn't Solaris itself ancient and should be upgraded? :-)

Comment: @Borodin: This is not true. Solaris ships perl 5.8.4 and of course they're supporting it, it's part of the OS.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: Perl 5 version 16 is the oldest version that is officially supported *by the Perl 5 team*. You can always find someone who will support anything as long as you offer enough money, but there will be no bug fixes to version 8.4, and I doubt if Solaris will make any attempt to correct any problems found with it. It is *not* part of the OS - it is merely bundled with it.

Comment: @AsishPati: There are many ways. Your question is tagged `Perl` so we (all) assumed you wanted a Perl solution.

Comment: @Borodin: I have access to a Solaris 10 system, and the perl there lists 37 locally applied patches. So if there's a serious problem (e.g. a CVE), then Oracle will probably solve it. And `perldoc perlsolaris` says "... is supplied with the operating system". Remember that not everybody is regarding just the kernel as the OS.

Comment: @SlavenRezic: I'm astonished. I would love to hear Oracle's reason for duplicating other people's effort in order to maintain a decade-old language out of step with anyone else's system. I would also point out that *"[Perl] is supplied with the operating system"* implies that Perl *isn't part of* the OS.

Comment: @Borodin: what's unusual about an OS vendor to add patches to their packages? Everybody is doing this, Debian, Solaris, RedHat, FreeBSD... Just look at "perl -V" of the vendor perl, some of the vendors (e.g. Debian and Solaris) list the locally applied patches.

Comment: @Borodin: Solaris 10 was released in January 2005, and perl 5.8.4 wasn't so outdated then.   Solaris 11 (released in 2011) has perl 5.12, which is a bit better.

Comment: x=$(perl -e 'print int(time)') echo $x with this code i can print the present time in seconds. Do i have some way to convert my date to some format and convert it using such code?

Comment: If you have a new question, then you should ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

With a little more effort, you can do this with your horribly outdated version of Perl.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::Local;

my $str = '2013-04-29 08:17:58';
my @dt  = split /[- :]/, $str;

$dt[0] -= 1900;
$dt[1] -= 1;

print timelocal reverse @dt;
```

[Time::Local](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aLocal) has been included with Perl since the first release of Perl 5 (in 1994).

But **please** do what you can to get your ancient version of Perl updated.

**Update:** Getting a few downvotes on this. But no-one has bothered to explain why.

Comment: x=$(perl -e 'print int(time)')
echo $x
with this code i can print the present time in seconds. Do i have some way to convert my date to some format and convert it using such code?